# Understanding the code in C involving processes

Tags: c

Someone can explain me why the first code the variable "v" dont change the value in the last prinft() and se second code the variable "v" change.

First code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int v = 5;

int main(){

    pid_t piid;

    piid = fork();

    if(piid==0){
        v += 15;
        return 0;
    }
    else if(piid >0){
        wait(NULL);
        printf("Final value = %d\n",v);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I know this code be involving fork() for create another process maybe

Second code:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// 64kB stack
#define FIBER_STACK 1024*64

int v = 5;

int threadFunction( void* argument )
{
    v += 10;
    return 0;
}

int main(){
    void* stack;
    pid_t pid;


    stack = malloc( FIBER_STACK );
    if ( stack == 0 )
    {
        perror("malloc: could not allocate stack\n");
        exit(1);
    }



    pid = clone( &threadFunction, (char*) stack + FIBER_STACK,
    SIGCHLD | CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | CLONE_VM, 0 );
    if ( pid == -1 )
    {
        perror( "clone" );
        exit(2);
    }


    pid = waitpid( pid, 0, 0 );
    if ( pid == -1 )
    {
        perror( "waitpid" );
        exit(3);
    }


    free( stack );
    printf("Final value = %d\n", v);

    return 0;
}
```

This code is a thread, but I can not understand the so-called clone () and what's inside there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forking a new process creates a standalone and distinct *copy* of the original process. Changing something in the process copy will not change anything in the original process.

Threads are different, they *share* everything. All threads are still parts of the same process.

While the [`clone`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) system call can create a new process (that's what happens when you call [`fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) in Linux actually) it can also be used to create a thread, which is what happens in the second program.

Answer (score 0):

threads  run in a shared memory space, while processes run in separate memory spaces. 
so in the first case using fork each process has different reference of the variable v while in the thread both has the same reference.